# IE error with javascript that works fine on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
document.getElementById("displayImage").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "image2.png"
```

I seem to remember that for IE, you need to add a `<meta>` tag of some description, but I can't find which one.

If it helps:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0;
>
> Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR
>
> 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) Timestamp: Tue, 6 Sep 2011 12:23:00 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: can you supply the part of the html which should be altered?

Comment: try debugging with the IE developer tools. The error might not really lie where the error console tells you it does.

Comment: <div align="center" id="displayImage">
 <img id="case" src="<?=$_GET['image']?>">
</div>

Comment: There's no need for a meta tag for this; the script should work in IE. Without the HTML document, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("case").src = "image2.png"`?

Comment: Same error with that MrMisterMan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, the code is fine; there's no need for a meta tag. I suspect there is some other JavaScript error occurring before the code executes. It's either that, or the elements don't exist in the document when the code executes.

Comment: Ah sorted it!!  It was window.history.pushState

Comment: Yep, I was just about to post that. IE8 doesn't support pushState.

Comment: Do you know any work arounds for IE8?  I've added an if loop for now.

Comment: Using feature detection will save you from errors in browsers that don't support it, and it sounds like you're doing that.

Example:

    if (typeof window.history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        /* code for browsers that support pushState */
    }

Answer (score 0):

try setting the src attribute for the image like this

```
var image = document.getElementById("displayImage").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
image.setAttribute("src",path);
```